# Uploads files in native s3 using java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am exploring aws s3.Which file system is implemented for s3 buckets and What are different filesystems used in aws s3? Most likely I am interested in native s3 file system.I need to upload files into native s3 file system using java API.

Comment: Why do you care how S3 is implemented? you have an API - use it.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not impossible to mount AWS S3 as a file system, the most idiomatic way to use it is via API. AWS provides very nice SDK to work with AWS services. Here's a couple of [AWS S3 examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3.html):

```
public static Bucket getBucket(String bucket_name) {
    final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    Bucket named_bucket = null;
    List<Bucket> buckets = s3.listBuckets();
    for (Bucket b : buckets) {
        if (b.getName().equals(bucket_name)) {
            named_bucket = b;
        }
    }
    return named_bucket;
}

public static Bucket createBucket(String bucket_name) {
    final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    Bucket b = null;
    if (s3.doesBucketExist(bucket_name)) {
        System.out.format("Bucket %s already exists.\n", bucket_name);
        b = getBucket(bucket_name);
    } else {
        try {
            b = s3.createBucket(bucket_name);
        } catch (AmazonS3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Putting an object:

```
    final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    try {
        s3.putObject(bucket_name, key_name, file_path);
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
```